# How to decrease the width of the sidebar for a specific page?

Tags: 7, theming

Is it possible to decrease the width of my right sidebar for any specific page only? If so, please shed some light on that.

I have created a basic page whose node id is 56. In that page I want my right sidebar region to occupy less width than it normally does. This can be done through CSS but I want to know if there is a way to do that through Drupal, either with coding or without it.

Comment: using css can be done

Comment: You can create separate tpl file for that page, and modify the class name or css for the same. Please explain your question in more detail, i.e what is use case and so far what you have tried.

Comment: or in your css, pick up a class selector form the page div.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers.  This really depends on what theme you are using, and on the exact situation.  As the comments are alluding, there are a few ways to handle this, all of which depend on how your theme is implemented.

Comment: What are the criteria used to define _any specific page only_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most popular themes add body classes for the current page.

e.g, assuming page is node 56 and sidebar wrapper is .sidebar-right, in layout.css:

```
body.page-node-56 .sidebar-right{
  width:180px;
}
```

Check your HTML body tag for the available CSS classes for your theme.

Comment: This is not good practice and I would definitely not recommend using it. There are several ways to add classes to nodes and pages. Use one of those instead.

Comment: @sareed, care to enlighten us as to why using body classes is a bad idea? To me, this looks like a perfectly reasonable solution to OPs question.

Comment: Using body classes is great. Just make your own and don't use the default `node-<nid>` style classes. It is bad practice because depending on the workflow you can have different nids on development and production for the same page. This of course would render your nid specific CSS useless.

Comment: And of course naming standards suggest against it. Using semantic names is a better approach. Examples: https://css-tricks.com/semantic-class-names/. Also, reusability.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`drupal_add_css()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7) to conditionally include a custom CSS file on particular pages.

You could also add a custom template in your themes templates folder. If you clear caches after including it, it will automatically be included as long as it follows the [Drupal template naming conventions](http://drupal.org/node/1882572).